# Problems loading scripts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on my first plugin and it is coming along alright. However, I am not able to load my scripts (CSS and JS) from my plugin. This is my code:

```
function my_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style('my-style', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/my-style.css') );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/my-js.js' ), array('jquery'), '', true );
} add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

I must be missing something... such a simple code to not be working :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty much correct, but check out [Plugins URL Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) and see this particular part:

> If you are using the plugins_url() function in a file that is nested inside a subdirectory of your plugin directory, you should use PHP's dirname() function

Basically, you need to load like this:

```
plugins_url( 'my-plugin/my-js.js' , __FILE__ ),
```

Comment: I tried that Fabio. Using this format you get the parent directory of the current file, so in that case it would be:

`plugins_url( 'my-js.js' , __FILE__ )`

This way I can omit the my-plugin/ part of the file path . I have echoed the file path and it is correct (`http://localhost:8888/wordpress_sandbox/wp-content/plugin/my-plugin/my-js.js` . I am trying to do this in my localhost... could that have to do anything with it? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I use this method and it works fine in localhost, so other than this really can't see what could be wrong.

Comment: ok, good to know. I don't know what is going on... I can't wait for the day I can just seat down and code without running into these little issues. I've been losing too much time with minor problems... it is frustrating. Thanks for trying tho ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it. My mistake was that I was using the wrong hook! Duh! In the admin side, you use the hook **admin_enqueue_scripts** and in the front side you use **wp_enqueue_scripts** to hook your function to enqueue your scripts to WordPress.

Here is a simple example to import from your plugin. If you want to enqueue scripts from your theme, you should use get_template_directory_uri() function to get the proper path.

From your **custom plugin** to the **admin side**:

```
function load_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style', plugins_url( 'my-style.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', plugins_url( 'my-js.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true );    

} add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'guide_express_scripts' );
```

From your **custom plugin** to the **front side**:

```
function load_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style', plugins_url( 'my-style.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', plugins_url( 'my-js.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true );    

} add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'guide_express_scripts' );
```